# FAQ: What's this developer license for?

Tags: discussion, web8

So, this is probably against the rules, but Tridion Meta sounds like the best place to reach out to you guys and explain a few things about the Free Developer Licenses that SDL is now giving away to people asking for it (as I announced at the Tridion Developer Summit in Amsterdam). I've been getting a lot of requests that don't make sense, so I want to post a few details about it.

- Question: Who can apply to a Developer License?
- Question: Are there restrictions in how I can use it?
- Question: Are there restrictions in the license itself?
- Question: How do I get one?
- Question: Can I use this license for Open Source projects, like the PowerTools or the DXA?
- Question: Can I get Tridion Sites 9 by requesting a developer license?

Please note that this program has been discontinued in 2020. Please contact customer support for new licenses, if needed...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- **Question: Who can apply to a Developer License?**

Any *individual* person can ask for a developer license. These licenses are non-commercial, research licenses that can be used for self-learning. If you are a customer or a partner you have *much better* licenses available for you. Use those instead.

- **Question: Are there restrictions in how I can use it?**

Yes, you cannot use these licenses for commercial development - anything you get paid to do - and you're not allowed to run any type of service with them. They are meant as a way to make sure **you** can learn our software and be better at what you do with it. They can also not be used for comparisons with other WCM vendors or any such efforts.

- **Question: Are there restrictions in the license itself?**

Yes, these licenses have the following restrictions:

1. Valid for one year
2. Maximum of four (4) Cores
3. Maximum of 2 named users in the system

   - **Question: How do I get one?**

Fill in your request using [this form](http://appstore.sdl.com/web-content-management/developers/#119754).

- **Question: Can I use this license for open source projects, like the PowerTools or the DXA?**

Yes, you can. As stated in the EULA, "You may not [...] use the software for any other purpose than investigation and knowledge sharing."
Open Source projects fall entirely into Knowledge sharing.

- **Question: Can I get Tridion Sites 9 by requesting a developer license?**

At this point (November 2018), the answer is no. To get a copy of Sites 9 you need to open an incident via the [SDL Customer Support Gateway](https://gateway.sdl.com/)

Comment: Great news. *double-thumbs-up*

Comment: Awesome information, thanks Nuno

Comment: Thanks Nuno, For the information

Comment: Thanks for this Nuno!

Comment: Thanks Nuno, Where I can register for developer License...

Comment: Send an email to sdl.tridion.mvp@sdl.com